# How to save a file in the Downloads directory?

Tags: java, android, file, save

My Code is:

```
String MyFile = "Riseone.dat";
String MyContent = "This is My file im writing\r\n";

File file;
FileOutputStream outputStream;
try {
     file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                        Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),MyFile);
     outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
     outputStream.write(MyContent.getBytes());
     outputStream.close();

 } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

When I try this code MyFile creates in data/data/appfolder/files/Riseone.dat
but I want to create a file in DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS.

also I want the file to write in append for next write action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), MyFile);` corresponds to the file inside the `Downloads` directory of external shared storage. You might have seen older file in internal storage. Check it carefully.

If you want to append the data for next write, use append mode to create `FileOutputStream` using another constructor `public FileOutputStream(File file, boolean append)`

```
outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
```